# Tensorflow is there anything like parse_multiple_examples

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create sequences of my dataset. However, Tensorflow only provides the function:

```
tf.parse_single_example()
```

I tried to avoid this problem by using the `tf.py_func` and smth like this:

```
dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_func(_parse_tf_record, [x, sequence_length])

for sequence_id in range(0, sequence_length):
    filename = x
    # files only contain one record
    for record in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(filename, options):
        ...
        tf.parse_single_example()
        ...
        break # only one sample per file
```

So for every map call I read `#sequence_length` files. However, this cannot be done parallel since `tf.py_func` does not allow for it.

Comment: Did you check `tf.parse_example`?

Comment: Yeah, the map function only returns a single example. So I cannot use that. Do you know what I mean? tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames) and then in the map function I only retrieve a single example to parse obs. @Maxim

Answer (score 1):

A tensorflow example is a single conceptual unit and it should be independent from the other examples (so that batching and shuffling work properly).

If you want more data to be grouped together you should write it as a single example.

To make things easier there `tf.train.SequenceExample` that works with `tf.parse_single_sequence_example`. It has a context part that's common for all entries in the sequence and a sequence part that is repeated for every step. This is commonly used when working with recurrent networks (LSTM and alike) but you can use it whenever it makes sense in your context.

Comment: Yeah, but lets say I have a sequence from [0,1,2,3,4,5] and I want to generate sequences like: [0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]. This would also not be possible with the `tf.train.SequenceExample` as in I cannot store the [0,1,2,3,4,5] and the generate the sequences on the fly.

Comment: If [0,1,2,3,4,5] are logically connected I would put them in a SequenceExample. You can extract the subsequences afterwards.

Comment: Yes, that would be my goal. How would you do that?

Comment: You can extract subsequences with slice operators input[:, 0:3] for example (assuming first dimension is the batch). Use `tf.concat` to take all the slices and put them together in single larger batch.

Comment: Hm, I only have one large sequence of lets say length: 10.000 and then I would need to split it into sequences  of lets say: 10.  Could you provide an example? Plus my input is a sequence whereas my output is not a sequence or a sequence of size 1